# Spring boot 3 upgrade: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/SocketUtils

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Looks like SocketUtils is deprecated now as a part of spring boot 3 upgrade. While running controller tests, I am getting below error. Anyone have come across it and how was it solved?

`main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while invoking 'afterTestClass' callback on TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.cloud.contract.wiremock.WireMockTestExecutionListener@4362d7df] for test class [class com.example.springboot.HelloControllerTest] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/SocketUtils`

It is reproducible with simple setup of Spring boot 3.0.0, Java 17, **spring-cloud-contract-wiremock** dependency.

Following is the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-complete</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-complete</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- tag::actuator[] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end::actuator[] -->

        <!-- tag::tests[] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end::tests[] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-wiremock</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and following is the test:

```
package com.example.springboot;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;

@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class HelloControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void getHello() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(equalTo("Greetings from Spring Boot!")));
    }
}
```

Comment: The fact that ou get this error means you are having wrong dependencies on your class path. Generally stemming from the fact that you are trying to outsmart the dependency management for Spring Boot. That being said the problem thus lies your dependencies, please add your `pom.xml`/`build.gradle`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I updated the question with pom.xml used and it is reproducible with simple setup of spring boot 3, java 17 and spring-cloud-contract-wiremock dependency

Comment: As @M.Deinum is mentioning - Generally you should not add specific version numbers but count on the Spring framework BOM's in f.ex your dependencymanagement
`
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2021.0.5</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
`
With this version though I have the same situation and are also looking for answers

Comment: Follow up, I see that 3.0.0 is going with Spring Cloud 2022.0.0-RC2 (latest)
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-2022.0-Release-Notes#202200-rc2
That means your dependency should be 4.0.0-RC2 and this version has issues

Comment: The `spring-cloud-contract-wiremock` you are using isn't compatible with Spring Boot 3. You should use the one from the upcomgin Spring Cloud 2022.0.0 which is compatible.

Comment: Yep.. looks like spring cloud 2022.0.0 is the solution here which is releasing by mid december

Answer (score 0):

The versions you used are not compatible. For Spring Boot 3.x you have to use Spring Cloud 2022.0.x, see also https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud.

This results in Spring Cloud Contract major version 4, see https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-2022.0-Release-Notes.